# Listening to key presses from anywhere on the screen

Tags: rust, x11

I'm using [x11rb](https://github.com/psychon/x11rb), X11 Rust Bindings. I modified some code from [this](https://github.com/psychon/x11rb/blob/15153e514a4e3e4c116279f76ab1c3635abc05e5/x11rb/examples/tutorial.rs) tutorial so that I'm listening to key presses from `parent_win` (`screen.root`) rather than `win`:

```
use std::error::Error;
use x11rb::connection::Connection;
use x11rb::protocol::xproto::*;
use x11rb::protocol::Event;
use x11rb::COPY_DEPTH_FROM_PARENT;

fn print_modifiers(mask: x11rb::protocol::xproto::KeyButMask) {
    println!("Modifier mask: {:#?}", mask);
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    // Open the connection to the X server. Use the DISPLAY environment variable.
    let (conn, screen_num) = x11rb::connect(None)?;

    // Get the screen #screen_num
    let screen = &conn.setup().roots[screen_num];

    // Ask for our window's Id
    let win = conn.generate_id()?;
    let parent_win = screen.root;

    println!("win: {}", win);
    println!("parentWin: {}", parent_win);

    // NOTE: This window is not being used
    let values = CreateWindowAux::default().background_pixel(screen.white_pixel);
    conn.create_window(
        COPY_DEPTH_FROM_PARENT,    // depth
        win,                       // window Id
        screen.root,               // parent window
        0,                         // x
        0,                         // y
        150,                       // width
        150,                       // height
        10,                        // border_width
        WindowClass::INPUT_OUTPUT, // class
        screen.root_visual,        // visual
        &values,
    )?;

    let values = ChangeWindowAttributesAux::default().event_mask(EventMask::KEY_PRESS);

    conn.change_window_attributes(screen.root, &values)?;

    // Map the window on the screen
    conn.map_window(win)?;
    conn.flush()?;

    loop {
        let event = conn.wait_for_event()?;
        match event {
            Event::KeyPress(event) => {
                print_modifiers(event.state);
                println!("Key pressed in window {}", event.event);
            }
            _ => {
                // Unknown event type, ignore it
                println!("Unknown event: {:?}", event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this would make `println!("Key pressed in window {}", event.event);` log something in the terminal if I pressed keys anywhere on the screen. But nothing is being logged.

What's the correct way of doing this?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57dc93844e863d488c90d20cfc47d607)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive events from an window, you'll first have to request such desire, either when you create a new window or via: [XSelectInput](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Selecting_Events) (as a matter of fact, if you're only interested in root window events - like window managers - there is no need to create a window at all).

```
XSelectInput(
    Display *display, //display connection
    Window w,         //e.g. DefaultRootWindow(display)
    long event_mask   //KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask
);
```

Now, i have no experience in rust at all, therefore i don't know what the relevant rust code would be.

**Hint**:

- In a multi monitor setup, there is a probability to have more than one root window, in that case you can specify `RootWindow(display, screen_number)` as paramater `w` (`ScreenCount(display)` will give you the number of screens).
- Only windows with the input focus will receive key events, so if another window has the input focus, you probably will not receive any events. For that you could do [Keyboard Grabbing](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Keyboard_Grabbing), but that would require to pass the events to the proper client afterwards.